# Standard Error for Proportion of Successes in Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: self-study, standard-error, monte-carlo, bernoulli-distribution

First note, this is for an assignment. I've been through all our notes, researched online and still unsure on this.

We are asked to run a stochastic simulation where, at the end of each run, there is either a success or failure. This is to then give an estimation of probability of success given the conditions in the question but we are also asked to give an appropriate standard error for this estimate.

Considering that the Monte Carlo standard error is:
$$s.e = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Is the correct way to calculate the standard deviation in this situation is to use a Bernoulli distribution and then divide by $\sqrt{n}$ - or what would be the correct way?

Comment: You have used the MC sample to estimate the mean, you should use the MC sample to estimate the variance $\sigma $ as well.

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't realize that was the case as I felt something like a proportion would mean that the standard error would be much different. I guess it all comes down to it's just a large sample of random variables and everything that comes with that? (as in, I'm obviously overthinking this)